# Apache Tomcat7 is not working on my Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

We have been creating servlets and animations on our Enterprise Java class and wanted to upload some of my projects on my home made server so that my classmates could see it online.

I followed this guide - [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04) - on how to install tomcat7 on ubuntu but when I run the command:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

It doesn't seem to load the tomcat webpage.

Output of the command:

```
root@coolai:~# $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Is it on how I installed tomcat7? Or is the problem from the configuration of my JAVA?

Edited:

This is the log file of my catalina.out:

```
root@coolai:~# cd /var/local/tomcat/logs
-bash: cd: /var/local/tomcat/logs: No such file or directory
root@coolai:~# cd /var/lib/tomcat7
root@coolai:/var/lib/tomcat7# tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
10 31, 13 11:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1808 ms
10 31, 13 11:56:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
10 31, 13 11:56:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
10 31, 13 11:56:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
10 31, 13 11:56:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Comment: That actually looks right.  Does anything show up in tomcat's logs?  What happens when you point your web browser at localhost:8080 (or whatever port tomcat is configured for)?

Comment: @IanMcLaird When I run my publicip:8080 on Firefox just says: "Unable to connect. Can't establish connection to the server..."

Comment: I updated it with the output of my catalina.out log file.

Comment: The part of the logfile that you show tells us that the server finished starting up at 11:33:47 and was shut down at 11:56:47. After that it naturally can't accept more requests. When did you try? How does the logfile look before that event? The relevant content might be hidden earlier than in the last 10 lines...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same, so i defined the JRE_HOME environment wariable and it's ok now
find the directory where you have the java jre and set the directory name

in my case it was:
export JRE_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre

good luck with it